# Functions Equality

Tags: functions

We have a polynomial of degree $n$, $P\in \mathbb N[X]$.

Let $f:\mathbb N \to\mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=P(x)$ for any $x\in \mathbb N$.
The definition of functions says that two functions are equal if and only if their values are equal for all the values in the domain that are plugged in.
But what if the domain is an infinite array as in the above example? Doesn't it lead to the fact that the both functions have the same formula EVERY TIME? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The domain is part of the function. You functions $f$ and $P$ have different domains and therefore they are distinct functions.

Comment: I know the conventions and that two functions need to have the same domain and co domain to be equal. But i need something more specific, like a counter example to it, i.e. 2 functions that are equal for any value in the domain ( let f1:A->B , f2:A->D be those 2 functions, where A, B, D are INFINITE arrays, and different from each other ) but have different formulae ( but no something like f1(x)=x and f2(x)=x^2/x ), or at least a proof that proves it exists.